# How to get the the index of an element in a triple nested array c#?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

So, I have this triple nested array deserialized from a JSON:

```
"Maps": [[[115.09049366110303, 116.30256509622684, 116.58246833041298]], [[25.0, 24.0, 58.0]]]
```

I'm already iterating over this triple nested array as it follows:

```
 public class Root
    {
        public List<List<List<double>>> Mapas { get; set; }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(textJson.text);  

    
        foreach (var item in myDeserializedClass.Maps)
        {
            foreach (var x in item)
            {
                foreach (var y in x)
                {
                   ...
                }
            }
        }    

    }
```

But since it's with foreach, how can I get the index of an specific element on that list, for example, the index of the element 25, so I can use this specific element somewhere else?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. "But since it's with foreach, " Is somebody forcing you to use foreach? and not a old-school for loop? In your example I see only a double nested array. How do you come up with 3 lists ?

Comment: "_how can I get the index of an specific element on that list, for example, the index of the element 25, so I can use this specific element somewhere else?_" I don't understand. If you are already knowing the element you are looking for (25), then just use the element (25) directly whereever else. Not sure why you would need some index for that. Also, the list/array index of an element is of course relative to the array/list the element is contained within. So, basically the index of 25 would be relative to the array/list \[25.0, 24.0, 58.0\] only (with the index value being 0 in this case).

Comment: oh it's because i didn't know how to loop through a triple nested array, so i saw this video and the guy used foreach, and it worked, i'm getting all the elements, but i just need a way to get the indexes so i can get specific elements there, if there's a simpler way pls let me know! :)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace my bad, i should've mentioned that JSON is just an example, in my project this json who's going to be serialized is dynamic, i'm just using this one as an example

Comment: How to loop through a triple nested array: attack each array individually. You can do a for loop over the outermost array, use `var item = outermost[i];` to get the first nested level, then you once again have an array you can loop over with a for loop, do the same again but with `item[j]`, and then finally you have the innermost array in a variable.

Comment: what is expected output here?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar the first element of that second list, which in this example is 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well simplest way would be simply not use `foreach`

```
    for(var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < myDeserializedClass.Mapas.Count; itemIndex++)
    {
        var item = myDeserializedClass.Mapas[itemIndex];

        for(var xIndex = 0; xIndex < item.Count; xIndex++)           
        {
            var x = item[xIndex];

            for(var yIndex = 0; yIndex < x.Count; yIndex++)
            {
               var y = x[yIndex];

               // Now you also have all indices "itemIndex", "xIndex" and "yIndex"
            }
        }
    }
```

then you store all three indices somewhere and can later also do

```
var y = myDeserializedClass.Mapas[itemIndex][xIndex][yIndex]
```

Comment: thank you so much, i was using foreach only because i didn't know how to iterate through a triple nested array in the first place, i just learned with foreach in a tutorial, but anyway, thanks again, it was super helpful! :)